# Change a variable inside from a if statement so the stament isnt true Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a loop that every 1 second calls a def() with a function that has an if statement, so I need that if that statement is true, to only execute it once, So I thought to multiply the variable so the if statment isn't true again, but I have an error.

```
i = 0
x = 0
def test():
    if i > x:
        print("i > x")
        x = i * 10


while 1:
    test()

    time.sleep(1)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 14, in <module>
    dynamicStopLoss()
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 7, in dynamicStopLoss
    if i > x:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Provide the error as text, not an image. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) on [meta].

Comment: In this case, the problem is that you're defining `x` as a global, but accessing it as a local.

Comment: Relevant - https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword